# How to pass parameter (= path with * ) to bash script

Tags: bash, ubuntu

can anyone here tell me why the * is not passed to the bash shell script?

My script named as top40 is

```
 #!/bin/bash
 sudo du -shx $1 | sort -rh | head -n 40
```

when I try to run it as `top40 /var/*` the * is ignored. It is like `top40 /var` but I want to see the top 40`s size of the directories.

when I do it whithout script and type it on the prompt, it works fine.

I really can not find the reason for this.
Thanks for opening my eyes. I use Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: Wildcards are expanded before your script is called. (You'll find that `$2`, `$3` etc are defined.)

Comment: Change `$1` to `"$@"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basic shell [expansion](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html).  Because the calling shell recognizes the `*` as a wildcard character, it's actually [interpreting that for you](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html), and passing a list of all the items in /var/ to your script.

If you [escape](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/escapingsection.html) the wildcard, or [quote](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quoting.html) the wildcard to prevent it from being expanded in the calling shell, it will pass to your script the way you expect it to.

Here are two examples that will probably do what you want if my understanding of your intent is correct.

- `/path/to/script.sh '/var/run/*'`

  - this example prevents shell interpretation by putting the asterisk in a single quoted string, which bypasses expansion and gets passed as-is to the script.
- `/path/to/script.sh /var/run/\*`

  - this example just escapes the single asterisk character from shell expansion.

Both of these examples result in the string `/var/run/*` being passed AS-IS, to your script where they become `$1`.

Comment: Thank you - I learnt a lot with your answer.